# Push view controller in ToolbarController Material

Tags: cosmicmind

I'm using Material framework by cosmicmind for my iOS app. My main interface is a ViewController embedded in a ToolbarController.
Is there any way to achieve animation like pushViewController in a UINavigationController?

I've tried the transition function with no luck.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should use the NavigationController, which is a subclass of UINavigationController and gives you the exact same look as the ToolbarController. Here is a [NavigationController sample project](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Samples/tree/master/Material/Programmatic/NavigationController) :) All the best

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to present a view controller from Toolbar controller.

Use this:

```
if let vc = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle:nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as? SecondViewController {
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Make sure that you set view controllers identifier on Storyboard for the view controller you want to present. 
In this case identifier is:

> SecondViewController

Comment: That works too :), but it wont give the `pushViewController` style animation.

Comment: `animated: true` will make the animation. I am not sure what's the difference.

Comment: `pushViewController` will animate it from the side with swipe ability and enable the back button. `present` will animate it in, but you will need to `dismiss` it. Depends on the flow you are looking for.